# Brush is blocky and noisy to sculpt with despite quite low dyntopology detail value

Tags: modeling

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47fb7.jpg) shows a tutorial I attempted to match with my settings, and yet still couldn't find a way to naturally sculpt the mesh without making it increasingly blocky.

Comment: You can add the image here. I would ask if you have increased the dyntopo resolution first, this seems to be really low like 12.00 or something.

Comment: It was on 8.0px, to match the tutorial on the left which had a much better result from what looked like the same settings.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)